# How to merge values with the same key in a json in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I would like to merge a value from 1 json to another based on a particular Key value.
Please find below code, which gives me only an empty array while merging. The main problem is that **gp_value** var is having an empty array.
I would like to merge **gpfinalgpid** from **gpidmgmtfinal.json** to **gp-test.json** matching the **gpfinalnet** and **networkId** value.

I have tried adding **First** fo the gp_value,  but that throws an error saying **No first item, sequence was empty**

```
tasks:
   - name: Combine GP
     vars:
       gplist: "{{ lookup('file', 'gpidmgmtfinal.json') | from_json }}"
       gpconf: "{{ lookup('file', 'gp-test.json') | from_json }}"
       gp: >-
         {{
          gplist 
          | json_query('results[*].ansible_facts[]')
         }}
       gp_value: >-
         {{
          gp
          | selectattr('gpfinalnet', '==', item.networkId)
          | map(attribute='gpfinalgpid')
          | list
          | default(None)
         }}
     set_fact:
       value: "{{ gp_value }}"
       result: >-
         {{ 
            result | default([])
           +
            [item | combine({'gpid': gp_value})]
         }}
     loop:  "{{ gpconf }}"
```

gplist JSON:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "gpfinalgpid": "101",
                "gpfinalnet": "L_456789 "
            },
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": [
                {
                    "gpmgmtcurrent": {
                        "L_456789": [
                            "102"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "L_456789": [
                        "101"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "gpfinalgpid": "103",
                "gpfinalnet": "N_11447788 "
            },
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": [
                {
                    "gpmgmtcurrent": {
                        "N_11447788": [
                            "101"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "N_11447788": [
                        "103"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "skipped": false
}
```

gpconf JSON:

```
[
    {
"name": "MGMT",
"applianceIp": "2.2.2.2",
    "groupPolicyId": "100",
    "networkId": "L_456789",
"subnet": "2.2.2.1/28"
},
        {
"name": "MGMT",
"applianceIp": "1.1.1.2",
    "groupPolicyId": "101",
    "networkId": "N_11447788",
"subnet": "1.1.1.1/28"
}        ]
```

Current Output: The new line with key **gpid** but with a value and not an empty array.

```
{
                "applianceIp": "1.1.1.2",
                "gpid": [], 
                "groupPolicyId": "101", 
                "name": "MGMT", 
                "networkId": "N_11447788",  
                "subnet": "1.1.1.1/28"
            }
```

Expected Output:

```
{
                "applianceIp": "1.1.1.2",
                "gpid": 103, 
                "groupPolicyId": "101", 
                "name": "MGMT", 
                "networkId": "N_11447788",  
                "subnet": "1.1.1.1/28"
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a basic mistake from my side. I had an extra space in the gplist json for the **gpfinalnet**. after removing the extra space everything works fine.

With extra space

```
"gpfinalnet": "N_11447788 "
```

Without extra space:

```
"gpfinalnet": "N_11447788"
```